# FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2 (Connecting android to server failed)

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to connect my android app to a server to send and retrieve data using PHP and SQL. I used this code in my android AsyncTask

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


        String sender=params[0];
        String receipent=params[1];
        String mess=params[2];


        try {
            URL url=new URL("http://muzamilbukhari.******/******.php");
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
         httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStream outputStream=httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();

            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream));

            String info= URLEncoder.encode("from","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(sender,"UTF-8")+"&"+URLEncoder.encode("to","UTF-8")+"="+
                    URLEncoder.encode(receipent,"UTF-8")+"&"+URLEncoder.encode("message","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(mess,"UTF-8");

            bufferedWriter.write(info);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            bufferedWriter.close();

            InputStream inputStream=httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;

            while ((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                result+=line;

            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return result;
    }
```

But it works sometimes and doesn't work the next moment. I am getting following error:

[1 Please Click here to see Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQWOc.png)

[2 Please Click here to see Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sm4al.png)

Following is Logcat:

```
    --------- beginning of crash
       07-25 11:53:46.209 2851-2910/com.example.muzamil.chatapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
                                                                       Process: com.example.muzamil.chatapp, PID: 2851
                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
                                                                           at com.example.muzamil.chatapp.Utility.parse(Utility.java:9)
                                                                           at com.example.muzamil.chatapp.MainActivity$LoginData.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:101)
                                                                           at com.example.muzamil.chatapp.MainActivity$LoginData.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:55)
                                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                                                                           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

07-25 11:53:46.619 2851-2908/com.example.muzamil.chatapp E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xaa2a10e0

```
                                                                [ 07-25 11:53:46.657  1556: 6510 D/         ]
                                                                HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x9eb91020, tid 6510
```

07-25 11:56:02.018 2851-2857/com.example.muzamil.chatapp W/art: Suspending all threads took: 11.490ms

Comment: add logcat as text not as image

Comment: Ok now logcat has been added. Please help

Comment: your problem is caused by a null reference, `invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference` mostly this class/method/line number `com.example.muzamil.chatapp.Utility.parse(Utility.java:9)` you are using `.length()` on a null object

Comment: Server responses sometimes and it doesn't sometimes and sends back a null object which causes error. My question is why does it send null object sometimes(Not always)?

Comment: this has many possibilities, it could be a `connection time out`, so yuor object remains null, but i can't see this in the logcat you have posted, unless you have missed part of it, it could be an exception on the server that causes the process to stop before filling data and sending it back to the client, the server exception could have many reasons, meanswhile you can check http response code is 200 or not, and check if your object is null or not before trying to access it.